# Can I call an onChange event from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

In my React app I have the following code:

```
...
handleChange(event) {

    let chunkedText = []
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    let text = event.target.value

   ...

    //store the text in local storage with the key 'tweet'
    window.localStorage.setItem('tweet', text);

   ...

  componentDidMount() {
    //once the component loads check local storage and update the value if it exists
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('tweet')) {
      this.setState({value: window.localStorage.getItem('tweet')});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <label>
            <textarea
              placeholder="Begin typing your tweet here..."
              rows="14" cols="50" value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
        {this.state.length > 0 ? <span>{this.state.length} Chars || {this.state.count} Tweets</span> : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice in componentDidMount we are pulling some text from local storage and setting state. Ideally right after this (in componentDidMount) I would like to run handleChange. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You could pull the state from localstorage when you initialize the state, it depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Couldn't you just pass `value` to `onChange` instead of the `event` object? So that you can call it from `componentDidMount` like `this.handleChange(tweet)` and from inside `render`: `e => this.handleChange(e.target.value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the code to something like this:

```
handleChange(event) {

    this.handleValue(event.target.value);
}

handleValue(value) {

    let chunkedText = []
    this.setState({ value: value });
    let text = value

    //...

    //store the text in local storage with the key 'tweet'
    window.localStorage.setItem('tweet', text);

    //...
}

componentDidMount() {
    //once the component loads check local storage and update the value if it exists
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('tweet')) {
        this.handleValue(window.localStorage.getItem('tweet'))
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <textarea
                        placeholder="Begin typing your tweet here..."
                        rows="14" cols="50" value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </label>
            </form>
            {this.state.length > 0 ? <span>{this.state.length} Chars || {this.state.count} Tweets</span> : ''}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from the parts of the code we can see.
But IMO we are trying to do something like that

```
const updateValue = (value) => {
    // your code to manipulate this value;
    // this code was before in `handleChange`
    // like:

    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}


handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    updateValue(value);
}

componentDidMount() {
    //once the component loads check local storage and update the value if it exists
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('tweet')) {
        const value = window.localStorage.getItem('tweet')
        updateValue(value);
    }
  }
```